# php not able to get array value

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I have this problem where I can't get the value from the array in the for loop but I can access it in the while loop.

I can't seem to find a answer online, so help would be much appreciated.

```
while ($pos = strpos($logTxt, $char, $pos)) 
{
   $t++;
   $pos += strlen($char);
   $positions[$t] = $pos;
}

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($positions); $i++)
{
   $beginLine = $lastEndLine; 
   $endLine = $positions[2];
   $textToEcho = substr($logTxt,$beginLine,$endLine);
   $lastEndLine = $endLine;
}
```

Comment: Is it always `$positions[2]` that you need in the for loop? As it stands I don't see a reason for the for loop at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this could be pretty easily fixed by using a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop, because it is an array.

```
foreach($positions as $position) {
    $beginLine = $lastEndLine; 
    $endLine = $position;
    $textToEcho = substr($logTxt,$beginLine,$endLine);
    $lastEndLine = $endLine;
}
```

If you want to use a `for` loop still, I believe your problem is you are only referencing the 3rd position of the array (Key 2, as arrays start at 0), not what the loop is pointing to. You could fix it by doing this

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($positions); $i++)
{
    $beginLine = $lastEndLine; 
    $endLine = $positions[$i];
    $textToEcho = substr($logTxt,$beginLine,$endLine);
    $lastEndLine = $endLine;

}
```

Comment: `$endLine = $position;` plus `$lastEndLine = $endLine;`?

Comment: @vladkras That is a discrepancy that exists in the original code, I don't know the intentions.

Comment: Thank you, I was so fixed on that the while loop had to work that I got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$endLine` always has third element from array, because of `$positions[2]`. Try changing it to `$positions[$i]`

Answer (score 0):

You base problem is using constant index in `$positions[2]`. But your 1st line in `for` loop `$beginLine = $lastEndLine;` will always fail because `$lastEndLine` is not defined yet. You can use smth like

```
                              // beginLine      // endLine
$textToEcho = substr($logTxt, $positions[$i-1], $positions[$i]);
```

of course you need `$positions[-1]` set to `0` before your first loop or smth like this (it's not clear what's happening before)

UPD I've tried your code and concluded

1. it will not work at all if `$char` is the first occurence in `$logTxt`
2. it does the nearly the same as [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function

Comment: Yes I was aware of this problem, but I needed to be able to get the variable first so i could go further.

Comment: So set `$beginLine` to zero at first loop, not to undefined variable